# Why do I set Manager.prototype?

Tags: javascript, java

In this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model), below is the Javascript code,

```
function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

for corresponding Java code.

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
   public Employee[] reports = new Employee[0];
}
```

`Manager.prototype` is set in the above code. `Employee.prototype` is not set as shown in the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model).

```
function Employee() {
  this.name = "";
  this.dept = "general";
}
```

If `Employee` properties were added to `Manager` by explicitly calling `Employee.call(this);`, then why do we need to set `Manager.prototype`? What does `Employee.prototype` contains?

Can you please clarify the problem, if I do not set `Manager.prototype` in the above code?

Comment: If you want Employee properties in manager, you have to prototype Manager to get employee properties.

Comment: @aug: The whole point of the linked page is comparing class-based vs prototypal inheritance models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
```

is JavaScript way of achieving the similar result as Java's

```
Manager extends Employee
```

Without that line, `Manager` would not behave as other `Employee`s. It says, "if you can't find how a manager would do something, then he will do the same thing an employee would do". By default, all Java classes inherit from `Object`; similarly, all JavaScript classes share a default prototype. Just like you don't need to say `Employee extends Object`, you don't need to explicitly assign a prototype to `Employee`.

EDIT for a better example:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Animal.prototype.alive = true;
function Ursine(name, colour) {
  Animal.call(this, name); // call superconstructor to handle initialisation
  this.colour = colour;
}
Ursine.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Ursine.prototype.sound = function growl() { console.log("Grrrr"); }

function PolarBear(name) {
  Ursine.call(this, name, "white");
}
PolarBear.prototype = Object.create(Ursine.prototype);
var sheet = new PolarBear("Sheet");
sheet.name;
// Sheet
sheet.colour;
// white
sheet.sound();
// "Grrrr"
sheet.alive
// true

function Cat(colour) {
  this.colour = colour;
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.sound = function meow() { console.log("meow"); }
var fluffy = new Cat("grey");
fluffy.alive
// true
fluffy.sound()
// "meow"
```

Here, `sheet` gets `name` defined by `Animal` constructor, `species` gets defined by `Ursine` constructor, `sound` gets inherited from the prototypical `PolarBear`, which is a specific `Ursine` that acts like an archetype for all polar bears, and `alive` gets inherited all the way up from a prototypical Animal.

`Cat` doesn't need a name (since cats are cool like that), so we don't even need to chain to the `Animal` constructor - we say we'll do all the setup ourselves. `sound` is inherited from the `Cat` prototype, `alive` from `Animal` prototype, and `colour` defined by the constructor.

So - typically, you would assign in constructors stuff that is different for each instance. You would "inherit" from prototype (not really inherit, as it doesn't get copied, but looked up the prototype chain each time you try to look it up) the things that are same for each instance of a "class".

Comment: But `Employee.prototype` does not have those members `name` and `dept`. `Employee` constructor has those members.

Comment: `Employee.prototype` is for looking up stuff that `Employee` doesn't define. `Manager.prototype` is for looking up stuff that `Manager` doesn't define - and it is an actual `Employee`, which was made by the `Employee` constructor, and thus has those properties. (EDIT: even if they weren't added by explicitly chaining to the `Employee` constructor from within the `Manager` constructor, as RobG notes below)

Comment: @overexchange—those properties are added by the *Employee* constructor, hence within *Manager* there is: `Employee.call(this)` so that *Manager* instances also have them.

Comment: @RobG If those properties were added in `Manager` constructor by saying `Employee.call(this)`, then why do we need `Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);`?

Comment: It's a matter of architecture. Presumably, each person should have their own name, and not inherit them from another department; but you might have an archetypal employee for WalMart, and all other employees would "be just like that" - without explicitly defining the property on themselves, looking it up on the prototype. Both are valid choices, for different circumstances. Look more down at "Property inheritance revisited".

Comment: @Amadan  Sorry, I did not get you. How setting `Manager.prototype` has anything to do with getting `Employee` members in `Manager`? What exactly happens when you set `Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);`? What `Employee.prototype` consists of?

Comment: @overexchange—the *Employee* constructor add things like *name*, *Employee.prototype* probably has methods that all employees should have like *getName*, managers should inherit that. *Manager.prototype* will have methods that only managers should have, like *doRollCall* or similar. Usually, methods are inherited, data isn't (but of course that's not necessarily set in stone).

Comment: It doesn't in this example, because `Manager` constructor calls `Employee` constructor, which overrides them. But if you had properties on the prototype which are not created by the constructor, they would get inherited. Try this: `Manager.prototype.species = "weasel"` and see what `new Manager().species` says. As I mentioned before, reading the later sections of the page should help.

Comment: @Amadan Oh, for my example, setting `Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);` is not required? Ok. I understand now.

Comment: @Amadan So, when I say `new Manager`, In my example  `Manager` inherits the `name` and `dept` properties from  `Employee` because of `Employee.call(this);` but not because of setting `Manager.prototype`. Am I correct?

Comment: No, not inherit. They get *defined* by `Employee` constructor. But close enough.

Comment: @Amadan get defined by `Employee` constructor for passed object referenced by `this`? So, For my example I do not need to set `Manager.prototype`.

Comment: That is correct - nothing is being inherited prototypally in that example, so the prototype might as well not be there.

Comment: @Amadan So, This was the answer I was trying to get for my question.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand javascript object is going to: www.objectplayground.com

enter this code:

```
function Employee(id){
this.id = id;
}
Employee.prototype.getId = function(){
return this.id;
}

function Manager(){
this.reports = [];
}


this.manager = new Manager();
```

click evaluate.

now after you look at the prototype of Manager see what happens when you add this line:

```
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee);
```

after the:

```
    function Manager(){
this.reports = [];
}
```

The prototype of the Manager is now an employee instance, this means it has the properties Employee has.